# Error al utilizar el metodo getCurrentSession de SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate

Creo un sesión factory de la siguiente forma:

```
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addResource("com/jegab/persistenceEntities/Categoria.hbm.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Al querer obtener una sesión en Hibernate estoy utilizando la siguiente linea de código:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Esta retornando un error que dice:

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Era cuestion de agregar esta propiedad en true al archivo hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```